# Overlapping Rows/Columns Using Bootstrap Grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Issue:**
Attempting to create this layout. I also need it to be in 2 forms. Since you are unable to nest forms, I have been trying to use some styling to get the top left col-md-4 to hide and allow the one underneath it to slide up to make it seem like they are on the same row (even though they aren't). Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is what I would like to achieve: 
[image]

**Attempted Solutions:**
Without the use of rows, off-setting the top columns to create space on the left for the one below to fill :

```
<form id="1">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Hello</div>
      <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Hello</div>
      <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<form id="2">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
       <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
       <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
       <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Using rows, giving the first column a height of 0px also a display: none.

```
<div class="row">
  <form>
   <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 0px;"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
       <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
       <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <form>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">E</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
       <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
      <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
      <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
     </div>
  </div>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to show the demo?

Comment: @VibhorDube here is the BOOTPLY I was working with: http://www.bootply.com/OO0qbzBhJH

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin.

Just used a wrapper for whole of your markup and finally achieved what you needed using little JS initialization for the plugin.

```
$('#grid').masonry({
   columnWidth: 320,
   itemSelector: '.grid-item'
  });
```

Please have a look at the fiddle. It looks a bit ugly, though the purpose is solved.

Note: I have not used bootstrap classes.

**[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/vd2nbnur/5/)**

**[Full screen FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vd2nbnur/5/embedded/result/)**

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to use plugins. I really appreciate your effort though. It definitely is a solution, just not for my environment.

Comment: Happy that you went through that ugly looking fiddle. :P

Answer (score 0):

I think i fixed it with this, you were using to many columns.

```
<div class="row">  
  <form id="form1" style="display: inline;">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>


  <form id="form2" style="display: inline;">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content here..</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This will slide the next element to left, but according to question, he wants the div, which is underneath the first div to slide up.

Comment: That's correct. I had attempted this as well with no luck.

Comment: I think this could be used in conjunction with `style="float: right;"` on the first form.

Comment: Ah i see now, but why? why not just place it first? whats the point of splitting the forms?

Comment: I have one form that will contain an update/comment thread that will be submitted via ajax on the click of a "post" button and then one form that will contain numerous editable panels that will be submitted one a "save changes" button is clicked. Initially the whole page was in a form but with the addition of the comments, I needed to split.

Comment: so three columns and two forms?

Comment: @TazTheManiac correct. However, the layout that is desired requires the top left column to be in the bottom form and the top right columns to be in the top form. Otherwise it would be simple to just split the top and the bottom into forms but they sort of overlap each other.